# why are my MySQL Left Join query results mixed up?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I'm lost with an MySQL query (running `MySQL 5.0.88`)

I have two tables, one with `products` from different `brands`, the other one with `applications` (= applications filter products, so not every application displays every product).

I'm trying to query to get a list of brands depending on the application the user is running like so:

```
SELECT    p.brand_name
        , p.id
        , p.seller_id
        , a.seller_id
        , a.info  
        , a.name
        , a.application_match_keys  

    FROM  applications AS a 
    LEFT JOIN products AS p
        ON a.seller_id = p.seller_id    
        AND p.brand_name IN ( <<QueryString: application_match_keys>> )

    WHERE  p.active = "1"
    AND    a.seller_id = "2222222222222"

    GROUP BY p.brand_name
    ORDER BY p.brand_name ASC
```

Problem is, once I do the `left join` I'm no longer getting correct results, so for example:

```
=== products ===
id        brand_name  seller_id
123       A           John
111       A           John
124       A           John
999       B           John
xx1       C           John

=== applications ===
name    seller_id   info  application_match_keys
red     John        foo   A
blue    John        bar   B,C
```

If the user is in application A, his brand list should only include brands from active products with corresponding match_keys (= A), so I would expect the query to return

```
p.brand_name  application   info
A             red           foo
```

But I'm always getting the correct brand name with mis-matched application data like so:

```
p.brand_name  application   info
A             blue          bar
```

**Question:**
Is there a way to query this in a single query, or do I have to query `active products' brands with matching application key` first and then loop/query again to get the application data I need? Must be possible in a single query, too?

Thanks for help!

**EDIT:**
Got it. This is how it works:

```
SELECT    p.brand_name
        , p.id
        , p.seller_id
        , a.seller_id
        , a.info  
        , a.name
        , a.application_match_keys 

FROM  applications AS a 
LEFT JOIN products AS p
    ON a.seller_id = p.seller_id
    AND p.brand_name IN ( <<QueryString: application_match_keys>> )
    AND FIND_IN_SET( a.application_match_keys, <<QueryString: application_match_keys>>) <> 0    

WHERE  p.active = "1"
AND    a.seller_id = "2222222222222"

GROUP BY p.brand_name
ORDER BY p.brand_name ASC
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: If `seller_id=222222222222`, `seller_id != 'John'`

Comment: Try `p.brand_name LIKE %application_match_keys%` and remove the `GROUP BY`

Comment: @Asad i was also thinking about using `LIKE` but here's a scenario, what if some `application_match_keys` have this set, `AA,BB,CC`. It will match on that if you are searching for brandName of `A`.

Comment: @KuyaJohn True, maybe the OP has single letter data though. Let's see.

Comment: nope. Applications can be anything up to 35 characters

Comment: None of your table field names match your query field names, could you please correct this so we don't have to guess which is which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about using `FIND_IN_SET`?

```
AND FIND_IN_SET(p.brand_name, a.application_match_keys) <> 0
```

- [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Comment: got it. Posted my solution above. Thanks!